# Importing certificate on Windows CE and Windows Mobile devices via command line

Tags: windows, certificate, windows-ce

I need to install a new root certificate on several (~1000) Windows CE and Windows Mobile 6.0 devices.

This can me manually done by going into the Control Panel -> Certificates -> Import

However I cannot find a way to do this via the command line. Normal Windows OS(XP, Win7, Win8) contain a program called certmgr.exe. I cannot find an equilevant CE or Windows Mobile.

The C# namespace doesn't have any import method and I cannot execute the certificate file as it is not a registered file extension.

Appreciate for your reply.